# Item stuck in Tokyo JR "lost and found" station, not in Japan anymore

Tags: international-travel, japan

I lost my phone in the Shinkansen two days ago, and someone bring it back to the Tokyo JR lost and found station. The problem is I had to take my plane back to France before possibly recover my phone. They do not send item back and I don't know anybody in Japan.

Is there a solution for me to recover my phone?

Comment: Have they told you how you can recover it? In particular, can they send it to an address in Japan? If so, perhaps you could use a package forwarding service of the kind that is usually used for online shopping.

Comment: @fkraiem Nice idea, I looked into it but I found that they charge a fee on delivery and the differents package forwarding service I found in Japan doesn't accept item with delivery fee..

Comment: I don' t know a solution to the situation as I've never been in one. I live in Tokyo. Let me know if I could be of any help. Maybe I could pick it up and courier it to France?

Comment: Part of the problem is going to be getting it shipped because lithium ion batteries are not allowed in air mail.

Comment: @SomeRandomPerson I may have found somebody from my company who work in Tokyo. I will let you know if I need your help, but thank you very much for offering it!!

Comment: @Jan I was completely unaware of that! I checked online, and I found that lithium battery which cannot be removed (like in smartphone) are allowed in air mail. Battery removable must be removed (from camera or things like that). And it is not allowed to send more than 2 devices with lithium battery in the same package!

Comment: @jan typically lithium ion batteries that are installed in devices are fine for air mail.

Comment: @Jan It's fine. Online stores send smartphones by air mail all the time.

Comment: @xuq01 The rules are not necessarily consistent.  Companies mail out new laptops all the time, but when I tried to ship a laptop overseas (to my company) from Germany, it wasn't allowed.  Whether or not it's _fair_ that companies are allowed to do this and individuals aren't, it's a fact to be aware of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally got it back (yey!), so for people with the same problem, here the different solutions:

- **Ask them to send it directly to you**: Work only if you have a friend or an adress in Japan. They refuse to send it outside of Japan.
- **Using a janapese package forwarding service** (see fkraiem comment) **to send you the item**: It may work if the item is still in the lost&found of the Tokyo Japan Rail (they keep it 3 days). You have to ask the JR to send the item to the shiping company so that they can send it to you. Beware that as people have noted in the comment they may not accept to send a phone because of the lithium batteries, but most of the time it should be fine.
  **This does NOT work if the item is in the police station**, because they will charge a fee for sending it and shiping company doesn't accept to pay fee (even if you want to pay them for that also). **(I am not sure if the JR L&F ask for a fee!)**
- **Finding somebody in Japan ready to send it to you**: OK, but you have to trust someone you may not know. Can still be ok because Japan.

At the end I found a collegue working in Japan who manage to recover my phone from the police station and bring it back to me.

### Some informations:

- The lost&found JR office keep the item 3 days before sending it to the police.
- The police station keep it 3 month before destroying it.
- The police station ask a lot of informations to identify the phone as mine, despite the fact that the lost&found JR office recognize it before and give a special item number to me. For example, they asked me:

  - A letter of attorney
  - Phone color and brand of the phone and phone shell, plus other visual informations.
  - PIN number (hard to know if you didn't record it before, so I end up giving my colleague the locking pattern).
- You may need to ask your friend to bring a cable to charge the phone.

It has been a long way for me, my colleague call the police station 3 times to be sure to have all the documents, I hope this will helps!